# Algebra Generated by a set modulo relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a very basic question I think, but it's something that can't find in literature. So, lots of times happen to see in a book a phrase of the form "Thus, we can define the free associative $\mathbb{F}$-algebra generated by the set $X$ modulo some relations". But I don't understand how do we define all this, how does one element look like? Can we describe in that "abstract" sense concrete examples? Can you give me the explicit construction of such an algebra?

For instance, I was reading that " The Steenrod algebra is the $\mathbb{F}_{q}$-subalgebra of $End_{\mathbb{F}_{q}}(\mathbb{F}_{q}[V])$ generated by the Steenrod operations $\mathcal{P}^{0},\mathcal{P}^{1},...,\mathcal{P}^{n},..$" and after awhile I read about the Adem-Wu relations and that we can define the same thing as a "free associative $\mathbb{F}_{q}$-algebra on $\mathcal{P}^{0},\mathcal{P}^{1},...,\mathcal{P}^{n},..$ modulo the Adem-Wu relations". Apparently there is an isomorphism among these two constructions.

Comment: Do you understand what "free algebra" means?

Comment: Almost :) I'm mostly working on Geometry, so this sounds quite abstract! Presumably is just like a free ring with an $\mathbb{F}$-algebra structure

Comment: If you can give me a textbook with this kind of things it would be very helpful!

Comment: It might help you to learn a little [universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra), perhaps by skimming through [this good online text](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/ualg.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element of the free associative $\mathbb F$-algebra $\mathbb F[X]$ generated by $X$ is just a linear combination over $\mathbb F$ of monomials, where each monomial is an expression of the form $x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n$ with each $x_i$ a member of $X$.   A set of relations, written as $A_i = 0, i \in I$ (where each $A_i$ is a member of $\mathbb F[X]$) generates a two-sided ideal $J$ in this algebra, namely the set of all linear combinations over $\mathbb F$ of 
terms $B A_i C$ with $i \in I$, $B, C \in \mathbb F[X]$.  The free associative $\mathbb F$-algebra generated by $X$ modulo those relations is then $\mathbb F[X]/J$.  That is, the members of this algebra correspond to
cosets $A + J$ for $A \in \mathbb F[X]$.    That's in principle reasonably explicit, except that it covers up the difficulty of deciding whether two members of $\mathbb F[X]$ are in the same coset (a problem that is in general impossible to solve, e.g. a special case of it is the Word Problem for groups).